# Playing Pokemon Go on a fast-moving Train?

Tags: pokemon-go

I plan to make a longer Journey on a Train, that moves approx 300 Km/h and there's nothing better to do then Playing Pokemon during this trip, but I fear that travelling so fast could get me banned.

Would I get banned for travelling faster than when I usually just walk around?

Comment: You're not going to get banned for travelling fast (citation needed) but it's going to be hard to catch any pokemon or use any pokestops. Source: I take a train every day to work.

Comment: One current theory is that this game functions like Ingress, in which case you will actually be soft-banned for travelling that quickly. The "bubble" moves out at 60 km/h, so for a period of time you may find that all Pokemon flee from you, even after reaching your destination.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You won't get banned for riding the train. I travel by train a lot in Japan. One thing to settle your mind is that you don't gain the distance traveled toward hatching eggs. Pokemon-Go is aware you're not walking. You're not cheating or using strange apps, so there is nothing for you to worry about.

Tip: Getting Poke stops on trains. You don't have to click each item that shows up, just close the stop and you get all the items in a shorter time.

Comment: You can also pre-click into an approaching Pokestop in anticipation of it passing by. Once you are close enough it will 'unlock' (the circle will open up and the location picture will be able to spin). This saves you the animation of zooming in & the loading of the pokestop image in the precious few seconds you get at the Pokestop).

Comment: Also, don't go for super common Pokemon on a train, rarer ones might show up and you don't want to miss them while trying to catch Pidgeys.